# SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%'; variable values remain 0 even i enabled query cache

Tags: mysql, database, performance

When i run `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%`, i am getting following results

```
Variable_name|Value
Qcache_free_blocks|0
Qcache_free_memory|0
Qcache_hits|0
Qcache_inserts|0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes|0
Qcache_not_cached|0
Qcache_queries_in_cache|0
Qcache_total_blocks|0
```

But i enabled all cache settings in mysql server and i am getting following result for my query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%query_cache%'`;

```
Variable_name|Value
have_query_cache|YES
query_cache_limit|2147483648
query_cache_min_res_unit|4096
query_cache_size|2147483648
query_cache_type|ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate|OFF
```

Can anyone help me why my Qcache values are remain zero.. ? I need to do this to improve all my query performance. Currently my innodb table having 3 million records when i try to put my business logic as stored procedure i cant able to get any response from it. Also i already changed all the possible innodb buffer values on my my.conf file but still its very very slow. Give some suggestions for me to improve its performance.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you running 32 bit or 64bit MySQL?  How much RAM is available on your box?  It looks as if yr 2G cache limit is being treated as 0.  Why not try 128M in your system my.cnf?

Comment: The query cache is used to cache results from fixed queries.  If you are using innodb as your engine, you will find that the InnoDB Buffer Pool sizing is far more important.  Look at my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf in you documentation directory.

Comment: @TerryE Thanks for your response. My server is 64 bit MySql and Ram is 16 Gb.. Also i tried my-innodb-heavey-4G.cnf. When i try to use that mysql server stop running. i changed my innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=50M and InnoDB Buffer Pool Sixe  = 4095M. Dont know still its very slow.. Indexing also done

Comment: Satheesh, caches are caches: they should fit inside memory constraints.  Try a pool size of 1G.  If you are properly indexed and using a sensible locking strategy, then you shouldn't have the problems you discuss.  Are you doing the std stuff, like looking at the slow query logs?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite old, but in case u havent still got an answer, query caches dont work for stored procedures is whats been given here, around in the 10th line

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-operation.html

Comment: Yes you are correct.. Cache is not used for subquery of an outer query, body of a stored function, trigger, or event. Thanks for your contribution on this question.